# DHCP server cannot execute script: permission denied exit 32512

Tags: server, permissions, dhcp

I created a DHCP server on ubuntu 18:04 using isc-dhcp-server that normally works. I want to run a script located in /user/sbin but get error of permission denied with exit status 32512. Probably it's a permission error but I'm not expert. This is my dhcp server located in:

/etc/dhcp/dhcpd.conf

```
default-lease-time 86400;
max-lease-time 7200;

ignore client-updates;
authoritative;

use-host-decl-names on;
log-facility local7;


subnet 192.168.1.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    range 192.168.1.101 192.168.1.150;
    option subnet-mask 255.255.255.0;
    option routers 192.168.1.3;
    option domain-name-servers 192.168.1.100;
    ddns-rev-domainname "in-addr.arpa.";
}

on commit {
    set ClientIP = binary-to-ascii(10, 8, ".", leased-address);
    set ClientMac = binary-to-ascii(16, 8, ":", substring(hardware, 1, 6));
    log(concat("Commit: IP: ", ClientIP, " Mac: ", ClientMac));
    execute("/usr/sbin/update_DB.sh", "commit", ClientIP, ClientMac);
}
```

/var/log/syslog

```
Apr  8 14:28:05 dhcp dhcpd[1223]: Commit: IP: 192.168.1.102 Mac: XXX
Apr  8 14:28:05 dhcp dhcpd[1223]: execute_statement argv[0] = /usr/sbin/update_DB.sh
Apr  8 14:28:05 dhcp dhcpd[1223]: execute_statement argv[1] = commit
Apr  8 14:28:05 dhcp dhcpd[1223]: execute_statement argv[2] = 192.168.1.102
Apr  8 14:28:05 dhcp dhcpd[1223]: execute_statement argv[3] = XXX
Apr  8 14:28:05 dhcp dhcpd[1227]: Unable to execute /usr/sbin/update_DB.sh: Permission denied
Apr  8 14:28:05 dhcp dhcpd[1223]: execute: /usr/sbin/update_DB.sh exit status 32512
```

/usr/sbin/update_DB.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hello world!"
```

anyone knows how to solve it, please?
Thanks!

Comment: show us the permissions for `/usr/sbin/update_DB.sh`, and check that root has execution permission. Show us `ls -l /usr/sbin/update_DB.sh`

Comment: -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 24 Apr  9 08:08 /usr/sbin/update_DB.sh

Comment: Do you have any idea, please? Thanks

Comment: perhaps edit your question and post the script itself.

Comment: I edited the question. My script does nothing special, just print a message. I should implement but first need to solve this problem.

Comment: try: 1.) force the use of the program `echo` rather than the built in one via `/usr/bin/echo`; 2.) you don't actually have a terminal, so redirect the output to a file, `echo "Hello world!" >> /home/me/temp/bla`; 3.) you don't actually use any arguments, so don't send it any, `execute("/usr/sbin/update_DB.sh");`

Comment: Solved. I posted the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved!

Running: `dmesg | grep dhcp` 
I noticed a message like this :

> apparmor="DENIED" operation="exec" namespace="root//lxd-dhcp_" profile="/usr/sbin/dhcpd" name="/var/lib/dhcp/bin/myscript.sh" pid=9646 comm="dhcpd" requested_mask="x" denied_mask="x" fsuid=165647 ouid=165536

So, the problem is apparmor that blocks my script.
I modified `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.dhcpd`, allowing execution of `/usr/sbin/update_DB.sh` through adding  `/usr/sbin/update_DB.sh r` to the file.